# php date() returning wrong month for specific months

Tags: php

I am extremely confused why date() is wrong on certain dates using the following code.  The months listed below do the same as the code example showing the wrong month in number form.

`echo $month` = September 2019

`$month_explode = explode(' ', $month);`

`$month_explode[0]` = September

`$month_explode[1]` = 2019

`echo date("m", strtotime($month_explode[0]));` = 10 which would be October

**The following months don't work...**

- November returns 12
- September returns 10
- June returns 07
- April returns 05
- February returns 03

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why you split the string how "September 2019" ?echo date("m", strtotime($month)); works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just hit me as I was reviewing my question.  I am posting this so that maybe this will help someone else dealing with the same issue.

IF you just use the month in strtotime it will auto append the current "day of month" and "year" in numeric form.  Because today is the 31st, it tries to calculate September 31st which doesn't exist.  So it auto jumps to the next month.  Same for all of the months listed.  If I change the code to the following everything works because every month has a "1st" of the month.

```
echo date("m", strtotime("first day of {$month_explode[0]}"));
```

Comment: To make it less confusing on future people that may want to visit your code; may I suggest: `echo date("m", strtotime("first day of {$month_explode[0]}"));`

Comment: I agree!  Much easier to read.  I updated the code to reflect your suggestion.